# wsp deploy error sharepoint2013

Tags: deployment

i tried to deploy my vs solution to another sharepoint portal. 
i did 
**Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath "pathofthe wsp file"**
and when i write the command which is;
**Install-SPSolution -Identity nameofwspfile.wsp -WebApplication ....mywebappame--- -GACDeployment**
i get the following error;

**this solution contains no resources scoped for a web application and cannot be deployed to a particular web application.**

any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicated that you should not install the solution to a specific webapplication, so skip that paramter in the install.

```
 Install-SPSolution -Identity nameofwspfile.wsp -GACDeployment
```

Comment: i tired that way but now its not appearing on any of my web applications

Comment: As Muhammad said, if you don't want that, you will have to change the scope of the feature(s) in the solution package

Answer (score 2):

Your solution has something in it which runs under farm scope, You got two options now,

Deploy your solution globally as Robert said or change scope of component scoped as farm.

[Check this link out for more information as guy is having same problem](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadminprevious/thread/3eca2d21-8da9-4695-94ae-9d19213cc4f8/).